# Preact.js - How to start a auto re run server like React.js does

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, preact

I would like to use a development server just like React does with `npm start`. But, with Preact when I use the same command it opens a static server and I have to restart it manually each time when I want to see some change in my project.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "yagoazedias-site",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Ready-to-go Preact starter project powered by webpack.",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --progress",
    "start": "serve build -s -c 1",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress",
    "prebuild": "mkdirp build && ncp src/assets build/assets",
    "test": "npm run -s lint && jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "npm run -s test -- --watch",
    "lint": "eslint src test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "preact",
    "boilerplate",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Jason Miller <jason@developit.ca>",
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test/setup.js"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost:8080",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^react$": "preact-compat",
      "^react-dom$": "preact-compat"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.0.1",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^20.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^20.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "offline-plugin": "^4.7.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "preact-jsx-chai": "^2.2.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.3",
    "replace-bundle-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.4",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.9.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "preact": "^8.1.0",
    "preact-compat": "^3.15.0",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^3.6.0",
    "preact-router": "^2.5.1",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "proptypes": "^1.0.0",
    "serve": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "main": "webpack.config.babel.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  }
}
```

Relevant links:

https://preactjs.com/
https://github.com/developit/preact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dev` script instead?

```
$ npm run dev
```

Your `start` script is doing `serve build -s -c 1`. React CRA's `start` script will boot up a webpack dev server which is what your `dev` script is doing.

`npm start` is short for `npm run start`. `npm run <command>` is just a small proxy that looks up the different commands you have listed in `package.json`.

Read more about npm scripts [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).